# Programatically creating ASP.NET PlaceHolders in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to create a loop that will write some data and add an ASP.NET placeholder to the bottom of the each looped item that I can reference later through other events. The code runs, but the placeholder isn't being added to the ASP.net page. I verified this by looking at the source in the browser. I am not seeing any of the breaks and the label text isn't displaying. Any thoughts/suggestions would be appreciated.

```
        for (int T = 0; T <= 26; T++)
        {
            Label x = new Label();
            x.ID = T.ToString();
            x.Text = "orem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla blandit id felis ac volutpat. Aenean tempor faucibus est, ac feugiat libero egestas sit amet. Aliquam";

            Response.Write("Control ID = " + T.ToString());
            string temp = "question_" + T.ToString();

            PlaceHolder pcl = new PlaceHolder();
            pcl.ID = "test_" + T.ToString();
            pcl.Controls.Add(x);
            pcl.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<br><br>"));
        }
```

Comment: is this code is on Page_Load?

Comment: I am also running this in Page_Load right now and I have not added a placeholder to the .aspx page.

Comment: You have added the literal in placeholder, but didn't added the placeholder in the page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to add your PlaceHolder to the controls collection of your page:

```
this.Controls.Add(pcl);
```

Comment: Awesome thank you! I thought that adding the placeholder also added it to the page. Now I know :)